# Django's support for translations in Javascript files

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization

I read and followed the instructions in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code), but can't seem to see the string in the javascript in the po file.

```
structure of my project is: 
cb/    
   cb_app    
   cb    
   static_files    
   templates
```

First I copied these into my url.py:

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('cb_app',),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
)
```

Then I added this script to my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
```

The actual script where I would like to get the translation, is as simple as that:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#id_sales_item').chosen({no_results_text: gettext('No results match')}); 
});
```

...and is utilized in the same html.

So is there anything more I need to do?

All I did then was to run the line below both from `cb/cb` and from `cb/cb_app`.

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en_GB
```

But still no sign of 'No results match' in either `cb/cb/locale` nor in `cb/cb_app/locale`

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the problem.

The documentation suggests  creating the messages once from the Django project and once from Django app. That way you end up with two `locale` directory. And in neither of those would the javascript translations be picked up anyway. This is quite a mess.

The cleanest solution I have found is to go to `settings.py` and insert this line (see also my project hierarchy above):

```
LOCALE_PATHS = ( '/home/kave/projects/cb/locale',)
```

Then create a directory called `locale` in the project-root-directory (see the path above)

Don't forget applying the entries into `url.py` and `html` as well (see above).

Finally now that the local's are unified into one place, go to project-root-directory: `/home/kave/projects/cb` and run these two commands:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en_GB
django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l en_GB
```

The first command get the translation texts from both project and app subfolders.
The second gets the javascript translation into a second po file.

Thats it.

Comment: You are my saviour!, it's sad that I didn't find this in django docs :(